# Python for loop #'s with decimals?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, decimal

Hey I'm pretty new to python just trying to put together one of my first projects but I'm having problems with the for loop. I understand it works like this :

```
for a in range(1,10):
    print(a)
```

I'm trying to do something along the lines of :

```
for ipscan in range(192.168.0.1,192.168.0.256):
    print(ipscan)
```

Comment: Does it work? Do you get an error?

Comment: No im getting "ParseError: bad input on line 1"

Comment: range won't work for IP address like that directly, either just have a range between 1 and 256 or use a class that handles ip addresses -[first google result for python ip address range](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html#support-for-non-standard-address-ranges)

Comment: Read the docs about the function [range()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range): "The arguments must be plain integers"...

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ipscan in range(1,256): 
  print('192.168.0.%s' % ipscan)
```

Don't get me wrong. I just don't want to overdo things.

Comment: @Thomas haha I know , python is going to exclude the last number in the range which is why i put 256, you can still have a *.*.*.255 ;)

Comment: @lockdown There isn't a built-in data structure but it doesn't take time to write a simple one as well.

Answer (score 0):

Range is ment for numbers only, so in your example, you need to create range only for last number in IP:

```
for ipscan in range(1,256):
    print('192.168.0.%s' % ipscan)// this will create all wanted numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try to use format method of string:

```
format_str = '192.168.0.{0}'
for i in range(0,256):
    print format_str.format(i)
```